# Taking a tree and making a list

Tags: list, tree, prolog

I have written a program that can take a list and change it into a tree.

```
build_tree([X,Y],'Tree'(X,Y)) :- !.

build_tree([X|Y],'Tree'(X,Z)) :- build_tree(Y, Z).
```

If I want to reverse the process and take the tree and change it back into a list, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Note that your tree->list conversion isn't a function since trees may correspond to multiple lists:

```
?- build_tree([1, 2, 3], T).
T = 'Tree'(1, 'Tree'(2, 3)).

?- build_tree([1, 'Tree'(2, 3)], T).
T = 'Tree'(1, 'Tree'(2, 3)).
```

If you want a predicate that can generate all lists from a tree, remove the cut from `build_tree` and apply it with a variable first argument. If you want a deterministic conversion, write a new predicate `tree_to_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, how would that deterministic version play out? Assuming there was only one possible list, from the tree, for example:

```
('Tree'('Tree'(nil, 2, nil), 5, 'Tree'(nil, 6, nil)).
```

Which gives:  L = [5, 2, 6]

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the cut from the first rule, your code it's ready to work in 'backward' mode:

```
?- build_tree([1,2,3,4],T).
T = 'Tree'(1, 'Tree'(2, 'Tree'(3, 4))) ;
false.

?- build_tree(X,$T).
X = [1, 'Tree'(2, 'Tree'(3, 4))] ;
X = [1, 2, 'Tree'(3, 4)] ;
X = [1, 2, 3, 4] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
flatten(leaf, []).
flatten(node(L, E, R), Ls) :-
    flatten(L, Ls1),
    append(Ls1, [E], Ls2),
    flatten(R, Ls3),
    append(Ls2, Ls3, Ls).
```

if you consider tree ass node(leaf,Element,leaf) for example

```
flatten(node(node(leaf,2,leaf),3,node(leaf,5,leaf)),X).
```

gives `X=[2,3,5].`

and if you wanna have bst

List to Tree.

```
insert(E,leaf,node(leaf,E,leaf)).
insert(E,node(L,N,R),T) :-
 E >= N,
 T=node(L,N,R1),
 insert(E,R,R1).
insert(E,node(L,N,R),T) :-
 E < N,
 T=node(L1,N,R),
 insert(E,L,L1).

list_to_tree(List,Tree) :-
    list_to_tree(List,leaf,Trea2),
    Tree=Trea2.
list_to_tree([],Tree,Tree).
list_to_tree([H|T],Tree,St):-
 insert(H,Tree,R),
 list_to_tree(T,R,St).
```

Comment: As often when describing lists, DCGs are a good way to describe the relation between trees and lists of nodes (flatten/2 above): nodes(leaf) --> []. nodes(node(L, E, R)) --> nodes(L), [E], nodes(R).